# Can i define a component in a single file component in VUE?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

suppose i have a single file component like this:

```
<template>
    <div class = "component">
      <subcomponent></subcomponent>
    <div>   
    </div>
    
    </div>
</template>



<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('subcomponent',{'/* definition of the subcomponent*/})

export default {
  name: 'component',
  components: {subcomponent},
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Is the code above a proper to define a subcomponent in a single file component? As i don't want to  add a new file to define another vue component in my practical use case.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Are you just making a SPA?

Comment: @AaronCloud sorry i am pretty new for vue, what do you mean by spa. And this is not work for me.

Comment: SPA is a single page application and I just looked at it again. You will have to make a new vuejs component and import it. Sorry I misread your code.

Comment: @AaronCloud well , I am not making spa, but i just need this particular component i want to define in this single page component.

Comment: @AaronCloud So there is no other to define a subcomponent in a single page component? Btw , thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue.component()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component) is a [global registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration). Once the component is registered globally, you don't need to use [local registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) (listing the component inside `components` block)

Your code does not work because there is no variable named `subcomponent` in your code...just remove the  `components: {subcomponent},` line and you should be fine...